# How to efficiently pairwise pool a tensor by trace value in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, pooling, max-pooling

I have a pytorch tensor `T` with shape `(batch_size, window_size, filters, 3, 3)` and I would like to pool the tensor by trace. Specifically, I would like to obtain a tensor `T_pooled` of size `(batch_size, window_size//2, filters, 3, 3)` by comparing the trace of paired frames. For example, if `window_size=4`, then we would compare the trace of `T[i,0,k,3,3]` and `T[i,1,k,3,3]` and select the subtensor with the smaller trace to be `T_pooled[i,0,k,3,3]`. Similarly, compare `T[i,2,k,3,3]` and `T[i,3,k,3,3]` to obtain `T_pooled[i,1,k,3,3]`.

This can be done by looping over `i` and `k`, but that is very slow and inefficient. Is there a way to vectorize this pooling operation to speed it up?

Edit:
Here is what I have tried so far. It uses list comprehension and for loops. It takes approximately 2.5s to run on a tensor of size (128,120,22,3,3).

```py
def TPL_Pairwise(x):
    x_pooled=torch.zeros(x.shape[0],x.shape[1]//2,x.shape[2],x.shape[3], x.shape[4])
    #compute tensorized trace
    trace=torch.einsum('ijkll->ijkl', x).sum(-1)  
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):  
        for j in range(x.shape[2]):
            keep=[ x[i,k,j] if trace[i,k,j] <= trace[i,k+1,j] else x[i,k+1,j] for k in range(0,x.shape[1],2)]
            x_pooled[i,:,j]=torch.stack(keep)
    return x_pooled
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show an example of such operation?

Comment: @Ivan I added my attempt to my initial question. It is rather slow, taking 2.5s on a batch tensor of size (128,120,22,3,3).